# Postman - how to access description field of request

Tags: postman

Is there a way to access the description field of a request to either set it or get it's value? 
I can get the name of a request via the pm.info.requestName field. In the reference documentation there isn't anything about the description field but I figured I'd ask just to see if anyone has a way to work around this.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. You mean the Postman API? Please explain better.

Comment: The postman sandbox API. I'm would like to use information from the request description field in a pre-request script. Just looking for a way to access that info.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a `console.log(request)` and see the different information available.
I'm afraid there is no description field data available this way ...